# ruby on rails javascript mixedpanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixpanel

I have a rails application that has a page that contains images that I want to on a click event send a message to the console for debugging purposes and run a line of code that tells a third party application im using for data analytics, that this element was clicked so it can track the amount of clicks.

The 3rd party app is called mixpanel.  As per the direction on the mixpanel site for javascript you can just write a script like so on a javascript event like. (/assets/javascript/new.js)

```
$('some element').click(function(){
    **mixpanel.track("Video played");**
    console.log('hey!');
});
```

This should on a click event, run mixpanel.track which will tell the application to track this element (#of times it was clicked), and name the event as "Video played" which is shown on a graph on the 3rd party site so a user can keep track of these events.

What I need to do is to use embedded ruby to get the instance variable and find the title, so I can name the event something like this..

```
mixpanel.track("video_<%= @vendor.name %>);
```

But I am having many issues.  One is that when i get it working, i get many console.log results even though i only clicked the element one time, and it will double up every time i click it.

I did not want to have to write a mixpanel.track for every image or button I want to track on the page so I wrote something like this.

```
$("span#<%=vendor.name%>").click(function(eventObject){
 var savedButton = $(this);
 console.log(savedButton);
 mixpanel.track("<%= vendor.name %>");
});
```

It was working initially, but it kept giving me results that were growing by 2s every time I clicked on the element.  The 3rd party app would show on a single click 1, then 2, then 4, 8, etc.. even though i only clicked a few times, the number would grow.

How can I debug this issue?
Why am I getting multiple console.log and events when I only click once?

Also is it ok to use embedded ruby so I can grab <%= @vendor.name %> in assets/javascripts?  Because then I would have to change my js file to js.erb.

Or should I write scripts inside the html.erb page that I am clicking on, So I can get the instance variables easily.  Since I may not be able to get instance variables if I run a script from assets/javascript folder or on a application.html main layout file.

Anyone with experience with mixpanel can you help?
Ill probably have to refine my question since Im not really sure how to ask this, but feedback would be awesome. Thanks!

stackoverflow.com/questions/8513912/rails-access-controller-instance-variable-in-coffeescript-or-javascript-asset-f

Comment: I would change that first line to `$("span#<%=vendor.name%>").on("click", function(){`.  This should attach an event handler to these span elements which fires on click.  If you are still having the 2x issue, please update your post with more information about how you are including JS in your Rails application (layout file, manifest file if applicable, etc).